# With mongodb java driver, maxAwaitTime not working on a change stream

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm using the Java mongodb driver version 3.8.0 and mongodb 3.6.3.

I created a watch on a collection with this:

```
MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = collection.watch().maxAwaitTime(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).iterator();
```

The documentation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/change-streams/change-streams.rst) states about maxAwaitTime:

> The maximum amount of time for the server to wait on new documents to satisfy a change stream query.

However, what I'm seeing is that cursor.hasNext() returns only if there is a change on the collection, not when the time passed to maxAwaitTime has elapsed.

When I turn on mongodb's verbose logging I see maxWaitTime set as expected in the getMore command.

How do I cause my watch to timeout when there are no changes? It seems as though maxAwaitTime should do this. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB drivers implement change stream as an abstraction of a TAILABLE_AWAIT cursor, and `maxAwaitTimeMS` is to specify a time limit for a [getMore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getMore/) command on on TAILABLE_AWAIT cursor.

The way it works, [MongoCursor](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/index.html?com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html) continues to send `getMore` command to the server in a loop until either:

- A document is found
- The cursor is closed
- An exception occurs

Only when any of the event above happens, the cursor's method [next()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html#next--) or [hasNext()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html#hasNext--) will return.

While none of the event above happens, the server's `getMore` command will continue to be called by the `Iterator` interface. The `maxAwaitTime` specifies how long to wait before the `getMore` command timed out while waiting for documents and returns even if there there are no documents found.

> How do I cause my watch to timeout when there are no changes?

If your application requires a time out after `maxAwaitTime`, the [mongo-java-driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) offers the [tryNext()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html#tryNext--) method on `MongoCursor`. This method will return `null` after maxAwaitTime if no documents were found, and can be called repeatedly by the application. See also [JAVA-2965](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2965).